# Vb.net datagridview last column set to read only

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I know you can set a column of a datagridview to read only if you manually add the columns yourself, but Is it possible to populate a datagridview with mysql dB and set some colums to appear as readonly... Whereby a user can edit every other column gotten from the mysql dB except the columns set to readonly

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter where the data you use to populate a `DataGridView` comes from (why should it?).

Use the `ReadOnly` property of the `DataGridViewColumn` to set it readonly:

```
yourDataGridView.Columns("the_column_name").ReadOnly = True
```

Note: If you use data binding (a.k.a. using the `DataSource` property), you'll have to wait until the `DataBindingComplete` fires before you can change the columns.

Here's a short, running example:

```
Dim con = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=master;User Id=sa;Password=whatever;")
Dim sqlCmd = new SqlCommand()
With sqlCmd
    .Connection = con
    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
    .CommandText = "Select * from spt_monitor"
End With
Dim sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)

Dim dtRecord = new DataTable()
sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord)

Dim dgv = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView()
With dgv
    .DataSource = dtRecord
    .Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
End With

AddHandler dgv.DataBindingComplete, Sub(sender, e) 
    '' access the columns in the DataBindingComplete event
    dgv.Columns("connections").ReadOnly = True
    dgv.Columns(2).ReadOnly = True
End Sub

Dim f = new System.Windows.Forms.Form()
f.Controls.Add(dgv)
f.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: In this case there are no colums set in the datagridview. I'm using auto-generated colums which matches the exact columns set in the mysql dB so therefore I can't use a specific column name since it may vary due to the the table I want displayed

Comment: @UnityGabriel You'll have to wait until the data binding completes. Only then you can access the columns. See my update.